How to see PIN login option in UAC of another administrator (domain account)
My users works with common domain account without admin privileges for computer. But they know a password for admin account (local account) of their computer. If they need install something, UAC pops up, they type password of local admin and they can install. They does not need to type username of the administrator account because I use “Enumerate administrator accounts on elevation” in GPO. It also works fine if I set up Windows Hello PIN for the local admin account. This login option is visible in UAC windows: Users can choose it, type PIN and install software.
But I would like to change it. I want the administrator account is domain account. I am able to set up PIN for domain account. It is not problem to log in via PIN for the administrator domain account to Windows. But if user works under non-admin domain account and “call” UAC, the possibility of typing PIN is not there. Only password.
Do you know why “Login via PIN at local account” is provided in UAC, but “login via PIN at domain account” is not provided in UAC? And how to change it?
Thank you
Al

I  don't have an answer, but if you're using the same domain-wide admin account for all your client computers, anyone can log in to any computer using that...

Specifically what you need is the "PINLogonProvider" to be enabled for the UAC elevation dialog.
